# spring kafka batch error handler implementation- need to know some examples

Tags: spring-kafka

Just would like to know on how to work with the batch error handler. Would like to see some examples.

My requirement is when batch consumer consumes the list or records if any poison pill (invalid record- different format) encounter, we need to just skip the record.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest version (2.8), use the `DefaultErrorHandler` https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#default-eh

In previous versions, use the `RecoveringBatchErrorHandler` https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.7.9/reference/html/#recovering-batch-eh

In either case, you throw a `BatchListenerFailedException` with information about which record in the batch failed; the error handler will commit the offsets for the records before that one and retry (or skip) the failed record.

You can configure the error handler to indicate which exceptions are retryable, and which are not.